# Eclipse : Add jar file and not depend on local machine path

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on Eclipse with a java project. In this project, I include a jar file. But when I include it, eclipse remembers its path base on local machine. For example : if I'm on Windows, the path will be `C:\Document\...` and if on Linux, will be `/hqt/workspace..` for example.

Although, in project folder, I create a folder lib and copy jar file to here, hard link to this jar doesn't change. So, when I copy this project to another place that jar file doesn't same with my current local machine, jar file will be missed and must re-config again.

So, my question is : How can i include jar file and not depend on local machine path.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use "Add external JARs...".  Put the jar in the "lib" forlder you have created in your project then add it to the classpath using "Add JARs...".

Comment: Ah. I see. Now, the jar path is : `[Project Name]/lib` thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome!  But... if you have solved you should formally approve my answer.

Comment: Strightfoward and concise answer, it deserves the green check.

Comment: I know the meaning. At the time I was commenting, your answer was not yet accepted. Just a note for hqt :)

Comment: @trapo: sorry, I translated the word "deserves" in the wrong way :-)